# Duvida ao exportar promise

Tags: javascript, async, promises

Tenho uma async function que faz um get pra uma api e retorna um palavra aleatória:

word.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const config = require('./config.js')
const axios = require('axios');
const axiosConfig = { 
    headers: { // speciyfy the headers
        'X-Mashape-Key': config.wdKey,
        "Accept": "application/json"
    }
}

module.exports = async function requestWord() {
  const response = await axios.get('https://wordsapiv1.p.mashape.com/words/?random=true', axiosConfig)
  return await response.data.word
}
```

Ai eu quero usar o retorno dessa função, no caso a palavra, como parametro em outra função que faz o get na api do google.

image.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const requestWord = require('./words.js')
const {google} = require('googleapis')
const config = require('./config.js')
const customSearch = google.customsearch('v1')

const f = requestWord

console.log(f())

async function searchImages(word){
    try{
    let URLs
    const URLsArray = await fetchAndReturnURLs(word)
    async function fetchAndReturnURLs(query){
        const response = await customSearch.cse.list({
            auth: config.ggApiKey,
            cx: config.ggCx,
            q: query,
            searchType: 'image',
            num: 2,
        })
        URLs = await response.data.items.map((item) => {
            return item.link
        })
    }
    return URLs
    }
    catch(err){
    }
}
```

esse console.log(f()) retorna Promise `{ <pending> }`

Comment: Esse endereço que está tentando acessas está pedindo a chave da API para autenticar sua requisição: [API Keys](https://docs.rapidapi.com/docs/keys). No `headers` você vai ter que adicionar uma linha com a chave da API `"X-RapidAPI-Key": {Chave-da-API}`

Answer (score 2):

#### O que está acontecendo

Quando você escreve uma função `async`, o resultado sempre é um `Promise`. Neste caso, como você depende de uma função genuinamente assíncrona e você não está aguardando através de `await` ou encadeando com `.then`, você está imprimindo a `Promise` que ainda está pendente (pending).

Mesmo que a Promise estivesse resolvida, o resultado ainda seria um objeto `Promise`.

#### Reprodução simplificada

Uma forma mais simples / isolada de reproduzir o que está acontecendo:

```js
async function foo() {
    return 42;
}

console.log(foo())
```

Apesar de não conter nada de fato assíncrono, `foo()` retorna uma promessa então o resultado é:

```js
Promise {
  42,
  domain:
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
```

(nodejs12)

#### Alternativa com async

```js
async function foo() {
    return 42;
}

async function main() {
   console.log(await foo())
}

main();
```

Resultado:

```
42
```

#### Alternativa com encadeamento

```js
async function foo() {
    return 42;
}

foo().then(console.log)
```

Resultado:

```
42
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa usar o `await` no `return`, `response` já possui o resultado da chamada, ou seja, a promise já foi resolvida.

Edit: É necessário usar o `async/await` ou `then()` na chamada da função `f()`, porque o retorno da função `f()` é uma promise. Exemplo:

```js
async getResponse() {
  const responseFromF = await f();
}

// OU

f().then(result => ...) // result contém o a resposta da função f()
```

Tem um artigo muito bom sobre o async/await, recomendo a leitura: https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: Então mano tirei lá mas continua retornando { <pending> }

Comment: Entendi, já tentou dar um console.log() no response? Pra ver se tá vindo algo. Não estou me recordando bem, mas talvez ao chamar `f()` você teria que usar o `async/await` também, mas não tenho certeza agora.

Comment: Consegui resolver eu fiz uma função assincronia no images.js e dentro dela chamei await f() ai funcionou legal, brigadão

Comment: Show! Então funcionou com o `async/await` na função e na chamada certo? Vou editar minhas resposta ali em cima, se te ajudou, dá como aceita resposta pra se alguém precisar :)

Comment: @leofalmeida, a resposta ajudou a resolver o problema, mas a explicação está errada e pode prejudicar usuários tentando resolver o mesmo problema. Utilizar `àwait` no `response` não irá fazer o código esperar por outra promise, `response` nem é uma promise, `await` simplesmente não fará nada nesse caso. A razão pela qual o usuário recebe `pending` na resposta, é porque o retorno de toda função `async` é uma promise.

Comment: Faz sentido, mas mesmo assim não há porque colocar um `await` naquele return, mas entendi o ponto. Vou editar a resposta. Valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Tá só pra ver se eu entendi, que realmente esse negócio de promise me deixa bem confuso:

1 - Quando eu tenho uma async function, ela é sinônimo de uma promise que vai retornar um resolve ou um erro, então quando eu uso a keyword await, eu to falando pra função resolver essa promisse e retornar um valor dela que seria um equivalente de then()?

2- await significa meio que "espere resolver( ter sucesso com ) essa parte do código pra executar a outra"?

3- o bot já ta funcionando direitinho só quero entender bem o que tá acontecendo aqui:

```
async function getRandomLinkInArray(){
    let word = await requestWord()
    let array = await searchImages(word)
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)
    let imageId = word.split(' ').join('_') + '.jpg'
    return {link: array[random], id: imageId}
}
```

nesse caso acima eu consigo receber o valor chamando getRandomLinkInArray(), mas digamos que eu tenha uma função equivalente:

```
requestWord.then((word)=>{
  searchImages.then((array)=>{
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)
    let imageId = word.split(' ').join('_') + '.jpg'
    return {link: array[random], id: imageId}
  })
})
```

como eu recuperaria esse resultado acima sem o async await? Eu teria que criar uma promise que encapsularia todo esse código? Eu sei que async function meio que é uma promise mas o que me confunde é como elas duas se equivalem no código.